# JS Filter/Map to get objects between

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to create a pager for an array of objects in a ReactJS project. I have a component changing the state with the 'page' of the objects that are being displayed.

I am attempting to use filter to grab the number of total objects between two numbers (the start and the limit)

My code:

```
this.state.items.filter((item,i) => i > page && i < (page + 12)).map( (item, i) => {
   return(
     <div className="col-lg-3 mb-4" key={i}>
         <div>{item.name}</div>
     </div>
   );
 });
```

there are 100 items in the items array and the page is set to 0 initially which should evaluate the filter to i > 0 && i < 12 (which I imaging is 0-11). Which seems to work....but when I click the second 'page' it should say i > 12 && i < 24 ( which I image is 12-23) but its not filtering the way I expected.

What am I missing. Thanks!

Comment: Well, your math is off. If `page` is 0, it will show 1-11 (since 1 > 0 and 11 < 12). If `page` is 1, it will show 2-12, since 2 > 1 and 12 < 13. Sounds like you're missing a multiplier.

Comment: change both occurrences of `page` with `page*12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Heretic Monkey mentioned, your math is off - you need to multiply the page number by the number of items per page to get your beginning index, and add the number of items per page to that to get the ending index.

```
const pageItems = 12;
const beginIndex = pageItems * page;
// Cap the end index at 100
const endIndex = Math.min(100, beginIndex + pageItems);

this.state.items.filter((item, i) => i >= beginIndex && i < endIndex).map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-3 mb-4" key={i}>
      <div>{item.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
});
```